# Table data comparison - Oracle

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, oracle

I have two tables with the same columns with identical data. The data in one of the tables may be updated, and I need to show a data comparison. The resultant dataset should contain only new, deleted, or modified rows.
Consider the following data.

Table1 data

```
EmployeeId  EmployeeName

10001       Ned Stark
10002       Jon Snow
10003       Robb Stark
```

Table 2 data

```
EmployeeId  EmployeeName

10001       Eddard Stark
10002       Jon Snow
10004       Arya Stark
```

Data comparison result (in the following format):

```
EmployeeId1 EmployeeName1 EmployeeId2 EmployeeName2

10001       Ned Stark     10001       Eddard Stark
10003       Robb Stark    NULL        NULL
NULL        NULL          10004       Arya Stark
```

How can I achieve this result? I've considered using joins, but I'm worried about the performance. Also, the key may not be a simple numeric key, it can also be a composite key comprising 2 or more columns. What would be the best way to achieve this comparison in the desired format?

Comment: The best way to do it is to use a join (in this case `FULL OUTER JOIN`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Een `full join` returns a row even if the left or right hand side is missing:

```
select  *
from    Table1 e1
full join
        Table2 e2
on      e1.EmployeeID = e2.EmployeeID
where   nvl(e1.EmployeeName,'-') <> nvl(e2.EmployeeName,'-')
```

The `where` clause says that there must have been a change in the `EmployeeName` column.  The `nvl` call is required because an outer join returns `null` when a match is not found, and comparing to `null` never succeeds.

Comment: In Oracle the empty string is considered the same as `NULL` so I'm not sure it can be used in a comparison here.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to do a `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.employeeid AS employeeid1, t1.employeename AS employeename1
     , t2.employeeid AS employeeid2, t2.employeename AS employeename2
  FROM table1 t1 FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.employeeid = t2.employeeid
 WHERE t1.employeename IS NULL
    OR t2.employeename IS NULL
    OR t1.employeename != t2.employeename;
```

[Please see SQL Fiddle demo here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/32e31e/1)